# MySQL copy multiple rows but change id

Tags: mysql, sql, import, duplicates, rows

I am trying to duplicate/copy rows in a database table in phpmyadmin by exporting the rows and then import them.

But they won't be inserted with a new value at ID so it keeps saying 'duplicate entry'. I have tried to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but that won't duplicate the selected rows, just change the value's of the duplicated key's.

I have tried:

> INSERT INTO `cms_modules_sites` (`id`, `site_id`, `module`) VALUES (337, 21, 7) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id`='NULL';

-

> INSERT INTO `cms_modules_sites` (`id`, `site_id`, `module`) VALUES (337, 21, 7) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id`='';

-

> INSERT INTO `cms_modules_sites` (`id`, `site_id`, `module`) VALUES (337, 21, 7) ON DUPLICATE KEY INSERT INTO `cms_modules_sites` (`id`, `site_id`, `module`) VALUES ('', 21, 7);

I cannot figure out how to duplicate the rows with a new id (or '' as ID so auto increment will do its work). I cannot do it manually since some tables have more dan 300 rows up till 900.

Comment: tried something like ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id= id+1; ?

Comment: @KrIsHnA Yes I just did, but that will change the value of the ID from the row that's getting the duplicate error. So it doesn't copy the row and change the ID, it just changed the ID.

Comment: Have you tried using `null` as the value instead of ''?

Comment: Why do you want to insert id every time, if you have already set auto-increment for the id? just copy other fields without id, then id will be automatically insert without any duplicate. try that.